# Docker Compose works but Dockerfile does not

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file. Running `docker compose up --build` results in an image that builds a container working as expected. But when I try to run `docker build -t myapp .` and then run the container, I get 'This site can't be reached' when heading to `http://localhost:8000/`.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8.10
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
EXPOSE 8000
VOLUME .:/code
COPY . /code/
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

What am I missing here?

Tried adding VOLUME property to Dockerfile: `VOLUME .:/code`, but no changes as far as I can see.

Comment: What is the actual `docker run` command?  The Dockerfile `VOLUME` line can be deleted (and doesn't do what you expect); in the Compose setup I might similarly delete the `command:` override (use the Dockerfile `CMD` instead) and the `volumes:` that hide the code in the image, just to make sure you're getting consistent results (so, just `build:` and `ports:` inside the Compose service definition).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Oh, sorry. I've been trying to just doing `docker run myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-compose.yml` file exposes maps port 8000 of the container to the port on the host. If you run the container directly from docker, you need to map the port using the `-p` flag:

```bash
docker run -p 8000:8000 myapp
# Here ----^
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but it didn't work..